# why did not got any error while validating my xml?

Tags: xml-validation, xsd-validation

My Xml is not getting correctly validated against the XSD.
I expect the browser to through atleast some kind of generic error messages when i open xml file

My Xml file is below
note.Xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <note
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:SchemaLocation="note.xsd">
      <from>Jani</from>
      <heading>Reminder</heading>
      <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
      </note>
```

My Xsd file is below
note.xsd

```
      <?xml version="1.0"?>
      <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
       targetNamespace="http://www.w3schools.com"
       xmlns="http://www.w3schools.com"
         elementFormDefault="qualified"><xs:element name="note">
        <xs:complexType>
         <xs:sequence>
         <xs:element name="from" type="xs:string"/>
         <xs:element name="heading" type="xs:string"/>
         <xs:element name="body" type="xs:string"/>
         </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="to" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
         </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element></xs:schema>
```

Both the note.xml and note.xsd files are in the same folder.
Can somebody guide why i am not getting any error? So Can anyone help me how to validate my xml file with xsd? Thank you,

Comment: Which programming language do you use?

Comment: This question has nothing to do with xslt. Re-tagged.

Answer (score 1):

Three problems:

1. `xsi:schemaLocation` attribute value
   should be a white-space separate
   sequence of namespace URI and schema
   document URI, like `xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.w3schools.com note.xsd"`
2. You wrote:

   > I expect the browser to through
   >   atleast some kind of generic error

   It's not clear that you are actually
   using some validation tool. No
   browser validates XML Schema when
   you open an XML document.
3. Your schema targets the
   `http://www.w3schools.com` namespace
   URI, but your document is under null
   (or empty) namespace URI. This will
   end up in validation error, even if
   you use the
   `xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation`
   instead of the `xsi:schemaLocation`
   attribute. Maybe you want to add a
   default namespace declaration in
   your input source like
   `xmlns="http://www.w3schools.com"`...